# Problem dropping item on WebBrowser component

Tags: c#, asp.net, drag-and-drop, browser

I would like to drop some controls from a self-defined toolbox onto a WebBrowser component. Because this component doesn't support drag-drop I use a wrapper to catch DragEnter, DragOver, ... This method worked fine while the application was still configured to work in .NET framework 2.0.

For some reasons I had to upgrade to .Net framework 4.0. All drag and drop functionality with my wrapper is broken. No events are triggered whatsoever. Events like "navigated" are still working fine...

I allready searched for possible answer and tried a few things but I couldn't fix it. Does anybody has any clue? Currently I'm thinking about implementing the wrapper given at: [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx)

Thanks for your time!

EDIT 1 (& 2):
I continued my search for answers and discovered the following stuff:

1. The DragEnter-event should be fired somewhere because the right icon appears on the browser. This icon only seems to appear when a DragDropEffect is set correctly. But I can't find the handler for the DragEnter-event (or other).
2. I tried to drop the wanted item onto an other screen part. This part of the screen doesn't contain a lot of components so it was pretty easy to implement the drop-action there. And it worked fine. I was able to get the object out of the eventArgs. But it's still not working on the webbrowser-component.

Maybe these clues can help you to sort out this problem.

Comment: I got it all fixed by working in the other direction. It's possible to specify some events in HTML-code such as "dragenter", "dragleave", "dragmove" and "drop". I added these events to the "body" tag of my page. Using a scriptingobject (specified for the WebBrowser) you can handle the events sent from javascript...

Answer (score 0):

The first way I actually got working is by adding some events and there handlers within javascript code. The events I've set are:

- ondragenter
- ondragover
- ondragleave
- ondrop (NOT ondragdrop !!!)

By handling these events within javascript and sending the event to C#-code I could handle these events as wanted.

To get to the control I'm dragging I implemented a little "clipboard". With this static class I'm able to hold the control I'm dragging and access it from the "onDragEnter"-code.